# Infinite request loop while trying to refresh access token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jwt

I'm trying to refresh jwt access token by using axios interceptor and refresh token.
The access token is refreshed and replaced properly in the local storage after a reissue request,
but reissue request does not stop. And when there is an error, it falls into a infinite loop which has already happened several times and caused shutdown...

I've tried to force the page to reload after getting the response thinking it is because access token is not saved properly in the local storage but i think it is not the case.

useAxios is a reissue custom hook that is used in every token required requests.

how do i stop this infinite loop?

```
const useAxios = () => {
const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
const refreshToken = getCookie("refreshToken");
const email = localStorage.getItem("email");

if(accessToken) {
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(async (req) =\> {

      console.log(jwtDecode(accessToken).exp);
      const expired = Date.now() >= jwtDecode(accessToken).exp * 1000;
      
      if (!expired) return req;
    
    
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}api/auth/re-issue/${email}`,
          {
            headers: {
              Refresh: refreshToken,
            },
          },
          { withCredentials: true }
        );
        // console.log(res);
        localStorage.setItem("accessToken", res.headers.get("Authorization"));
        window.location.reload();
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
      return req;
    });

}

return axiosInstance;
};

export default useAxios;
```

Comment: So if I get the flow correctly, `Token expired -> Try to get new access token -> do function ->Error in Try block -> do console(log) -> Token still expired -> Try to get new access token -> ..... ` You might have to do something in your `catch` block so that the program do not automatically try to get new access token..

Comment: I've managed to solve this problem by adding a response interceptor. And i have changed the logic into executing reissue request when i get an token expired error instead of checking expiration in every request. Thank you for the comment! :)